# Error with calling WebService in activiti process (Servicemix 5.0.0)

Tags: apache-camel, activiti, bpmn, apache-servicemix

My goal is to call succesfully a WebService in activity process.
I'm working with Servicemix 5.0.0. I started with example apache-servicemix-5.0.0/examples/activiti/activiti-camel , which I run succesfully via features:install.
Then I modified file OrderProcess.bpmn.xml and the main process in it looks like below now:

```
 <process id="OrderProcess" isExecutable="true">

    <startEvent id="start"/>

    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="start" targetRef="Call_WS"/>

<serviceTask id="Call_WS" name="Call WS" activiti:class="org.apache.servicemix.examples.activiti.WsDelegate" >
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:field name="wsdl" expression="http://localhost:8282/dodawanie?wsdl" />
    <activiti:field name="operation" expression="sayHi" />
    <activiti:field name="parameters" expression="${arg0}" />
    <activiti:field name="returnValue" expression="sayHiResponse" />
  </extensionElements>
</serviceTask>
 <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="Call_WS" targetRef="end"/>
 <endEvent id="end"/>

</process>
```

I use the class WsDelegate I found as a sample to help calling WebService from activiti process, and it looks like below:

```
package org.apache.servicemix.examples.activiti;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.Expression;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.endpoint.dynamic.JaxWsDynamicClientFactory;
import javax.xml.namespace.*;
public class WsDelegate implements JavaDelegate {
 private Expression wsdl;
  private Expression operation;
  private Expression parameters;
  private Expression returnValue;

  public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
    String wsdlString = (String)wsdl.getValue(execution);

    JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
    Client client = dcf.createClient(wsdlString);

    ArrayList paramStrings = new ArrayList();
    if (parameters!=null) {
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer( (String)parameters.getValue(execution), ",");
      while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        paramStrings.add(st.nextToken().trim());
      }
    }
    Object response = client.invoke((String)operation.getValue(execution), paramStrings.toArray(new Object[0]));
    if (returnValue!=null) {
      String returnVariableName = (String) returnValue.getValue(execution);
      execution.setVariable(returnVariableName, response);
    }
  }
}
```

I modified example class ActivitiRouteBuilder and this is the code after modification:
    package org.apache.servicemix.examples.activiti;

```
import static org.activiti.camel.ActivitiProducer.PROCESS_KEY_PROPERTY;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Handler;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

/**
 * Camel routes that interact with the business process defined in the
 * OSGI-INF/activiti/OrderProcess.bpmn20.xml file
 */
public class ActivitiRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

private final Helper helper = new Helper();

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    /*
     * This route will start a new OrderProcess instance.  Using the PROCESS_KEY_PROPERTY, we are assigning a
     * business key to our process to allow for easier correlation in later processing steps.  We are also
     * sending a Map containing additional variables to add to the process instance.
     */
    from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8484/test")
        .setBody(bean(helper))
        .setProperty(PROCESS_KEY_PROPERTY, simple("file:name"))
        .to("activiti:OrderProcess")
        .log("Process to handle incoming order file has been started (process instance id ${body})");

    /*
     * This route will notify a running OrderProcess of an order delivery event.  Here too, we are setting the
     * PROCESS_KEY_PROPERTY to correlate the delivery message with right order process instance.
     */
    from("file:var/activiti-camel/delivery")
        .log("Notifying process about delivery for order ${file:name}")
        .setProperty(PROCESS_KEY_PROPERTY, simple("file:name"))
        .to("activiti:OrderProcess:receiveDelivery");

    /*
     * The BPMN process can also trigger Camel routes as part of the process.  In these routes, the variables that
     * you added to the process are available as Exchange properties.  The next two routes will be triggered while
     * processing the order and the order delivery.
     */
    from("activiti:OrderProcess:processOrder")
        .log("Processing order ${property.orderid} created on ${property:timestamp}")
        .log("  original message: ${property.message}");

    from("activiti:OrderProcess:processDelivery")
        .log("Processing delivery for order ${property.orderid} created on ${property:timestamp}")
        .log("  original message: ${property.message}");
}

/*
 * A few helper methods used for routing
 */
public static final class Helper {

    /*
     * This method will extract information from the Exchange (using Camel annotations) and put them in a
     * Map that will be used for setting up the process' variables.
     */
    @Handler
    public Map getProcessVariables(Exchange exchange) {
        Message in = exchange.getIn();
        Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        variables.put("message", "pusto");
        variables.put("orderid", in.getHeader("id"));
        variables.put("timestamp", "teraz");
        return variables;
    }
}
}
```

And when I try to start the process through calling `http://localhost:8484/test` 
i get this stack trace:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: {timestamp=teraz, message=pusto, orderid=null}]
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1379)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:283)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:64)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:110)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.service(CamelContinuationServlet.java:151)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter.doFilter(MultiPartFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelFilterWrapper.doFilter(CamelFilterWrapper.java:44)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:274)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:57)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:377)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:176)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:100)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:330)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:202)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:143)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:310)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:446)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:393)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:240)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:233)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:188)
at org.apache.servicemix.examples.activiti.WsDelegate.execute(WsDelegate.java:22)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.JavaDelegateInvocation.invoke(JavaDelegateInvocation.java:34)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:37)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:25)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.java:49)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.java:40)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.execute(ClassDelegate.java:115)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:44)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:52)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.java:49)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.java:65)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.java:115)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.java:36)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:381)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:102)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performDefaultOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:51)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.leave(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:44)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.execute(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:36)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:44)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationProcessStartInitial.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationProcessStartInitial.java:46)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationProcessStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationProcessStart.java:45)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:80)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:546)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:541)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.start(ExecutionEntity.java:335)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:72)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:31)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:42)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.JtaTransactionInterceptor.execute(JtaTransactionInterceptor.java:59)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.RuntimeServiceImpl.startProcessInstanceByKey(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:55)
at Proxyf138e743_9da0_45a4_be4e_6b2c8e65cd48.startProcessInstanceByKey(Unknown Source)
at org.activiti.camel.ActivitiProducer.startProcess(ActivitiProducer.java:93)
at org.activiti.camel.ActivitiProducer.process(ActivitiProducer.java:48)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.namespace.QName
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 137 more
```

What should I do to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application bundle have some trouble to load the class javax.xml.namespace.QName. can you double check you bundle import packages?